# Looking for a vegan alternative for "savoiardi" biscuits in order to make a vegan "tiramisu"

Tags: food

I would like to make a vegan "tiramisu".
I have found an replacement for "mascarpone" cream, but I still need an replacement for "savoiardi" biscuits that is 100% vegan.

Where can I can buy something similar that's vegan. Any shop in the EU or US is OK but I'm not looking for a biscuit recipe.

Comment: What is the replacement for mascarpone?

Comment: This one https://www.veganobio.it/dessert-vegani/crema-vegamisu-250gr-schlagfix/ or this one  https://cuorevegano.com/products/crema-vegetale-per-dolci-al-cucchiaio-250-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found [in this store](https://www.cuoreveganoshop.it/products/savoiardi-vegani) Savoiardi without eggs.

Answer (score 2):

Things change over time and the stores may introduce new products or discontinue others, so ultimately knowing a specific store won't help much to people around the world.
I'd usually check some online store or a local vegan website with recommendations on stores. Some of them may be far away but worth checking :)

I know you did not ask for recipe, but as an alternative, making your own 'ladyfingers' biscuits may still be a good idea and shouldn't be a very big effort.
When baking, eggs can be replaced by using things such 'aquafaba', chickpea flower or 'flax eggs' (made of ground flex seeds and water).